# cordova iOS file downloads but isn't being stored properly

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, download

I am using `cordova-plugin-file-downloader` to download files from within my app (IE: .pdf, .doc, .xls, etc) to the users device.

Everything works fine on Android, and mostly works on iOS.  The file downloads on iOS but its not getting stored/saved locally - at least not to any place I can find it.

```
  $scope.downloadLink = function(fileInfo) {

    let storage_location = '' ;

    if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
       storage_location = cordova.file.documentsDirectory ;
    } else if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
       storage_location = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/' ;
    }
    let downloading = function(event) {
      var data = event.data ;
      if (data[0] != 100) {
        var msg = "Downloading file: " +data[0]+ "%" ;
        var color = "red" ;
      } else {
        var msg = "DOWNLOAD COMPLETE!" ;
        var color = "green" ;
      }
      $scope.startStatus(fileInfo.cfID,color,msg) ;
    }
    let downloaded = function(event) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.endStatus(fileInfo.cfID) ;
        event.target.removeEventListener(event.name,downloaded) ;
      },5000) ;
    }
    let initialized = function(event) {
      downloader.get(urlFile,null,newFileName) ;
      event.target.removeEventListener(event.name,initialized) ;
    } ;
    document.addEventListener('DOWNLOADER_initialized', initialized) ;
    document.addEventListener('DOWNLOADER_downloadProgress',downloading) ;
    document.addEventListener('DOWNLOADER_downloadSuccess', downloaded) ;
    downloader.init({folder: 'download', fileSystem: storage_location})
  }
```

in xCode, I get the following write line, its like an extra `/` is being added to the write path:

```
-[CDVFileTransfer download:] [Line 423] File Transfer downloading file...
2020-12-09 02:33:06.476605-0500 AttendaGo[6154:7065118] -[CDVFileTransferDelegate connection:didReceiveResponse:] [Line 771] Streaming to file /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EADA1122-72EB-4A9A-8BF9-75D3F57E0147/Documents/download//Word1.DOC
2020-12-09 02:33:06.484266-0500 AttendaGo[6154:7065129] File Transfer Finished with response code 200
2020-12-09 02:33:06.484548-0500 AttendaGo[6154:7065129] -[CDVFileTransferDelegate connectionDidFinishLoading:] [Line 637] File Transfer Download success
```

Specifically, this is the path, look at the end, before the file name is the double `//` -

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EADA1122-72EB-4A9A-8BF9-75D3F57E0147/Documents/download//Word1.DOC
```

On Android, I can find the file in the users general `download` folder, but on iOS there is no such folder, and even if there was, the double // before the file name would still mess things up.  Additionally, the path its trying to save to implies the file is being saved in the app, versus in the general "Downloads/Documents" folders.

How can I get this file to save to the root `Documents` or `Downloads` folder...the public one....on iOS?

## =========
update

I then outputted the file systems the plugin is grabbing and got this,

```
document.addEventListener('DOWNLOADER_gotFileSystem', function() {
  console.log(event.data) ;
}) ;
document.addEventListener('DOWNLOADER_gotFolder', function() {
  console.log(event.data) ;
}) ;

2020-12-09 10:10:00.585683-0500 AttendaGo[6196:7131475] [{"isFile":false,"isDirectory":true,"name":"","fullPath":"/","filesystem":"<FileSystem: persistent>","nativeURL":"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7C66DE16-73C0-4F10-99B8-8D42B8A01920/Documents/"}]
2020-12-09 10:10:00.592567-0500 AttendaGo[6196:7131475] [{"isFile":false,"isDirectory":true,"name":"download","fullPath":"/download/","filesystem":"<FileSystem: persistent>","nativeURL":"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7C66DE16-73C0-4F10-99B8-8D42B8A01920/Documents/download/"}]
2020-12-09 10:10:00.594968-0500 AttendaGo[6196:7131475] -[CDVFileTransfer download:] [Line 423] File Transfer downloading file...
2020-12-09 10:10:01.026073-0500 AttendaGo[6196:7131762] -[CDVFileTransferDelegate connection:didReceiveResponse:] [Line 771] Streaming to file /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7C66DE16-73C0-4F10-99B8-8D42B8A01920/Documents/download//Word1.DOC
2020-12-09 10:10:01.039425-0500 AttendaGo[6196:7131832] File Transfer Finished with response code 200
2020-12-09 10:10:01.040594-0500 AttendaGo[6196:7131832] -[CDVFileTransferDelegate connectionDidFinishLoading:] [Line 637] File Transfer Download success
```

Comment: any update about this topic? I need to save diles to some path of filesystem visible to other apps

Comment: @YoanAsdrubalQuintanaRamírez - nope.  Two years later my own post comes up searching for a solution.  For iOS, I had a work around that allowed users to download files from my server via a standard HTTP link; this would allow users to select the download path.  But I can't use this anymore because we are implementing a new security on our server.  I have read others using FileOpener2 to get around this but I am just looking into that now.